# Delete files that are not updated

Tags: vba, delete-file

Does anyone know if it is possible to delete a document that is not updated by a certain time.  I am trying to make a blank inspection sheet repopulate every night at 12:01 AM and if no one enters in inspection information for that day, the form for that day be deleted so I don't have a surplus of blank inspection forms saved.

Answer (score 1):

Yes it is possible.  here is the base code.  You need to change the if statement to reflect the correct time period.

```
Dim oFileObj
Set oFileObj = Wscript.CreateObject("WScript.FileSystemObject")
oFileObj.GetFile("File.Name")  
if oFileObj.DateLastModified < NOW then
    oFileObj.DeleteFile("File.Name")
end if
Set oFileObj = Nothing
```

Comment: just a thought: what if somebody enters inspection information and subsequently deletes it? it still produces a blank inspection form...